# SQL Server Data Precedence

Tags: sql-server

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) resource documents outcomes from implicit data conversion for MS SQL Server.  Unfortunately, this list omits the Numeric data type.  Can someone confirm that the Numeric type falls in line with the closely related Decimal type?  My immediate need is to confirm that Numeric slots above the Money data type.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to decimal, numeric does have a higher data precendence than money.  The following returns numeric as the result.

```
DECLARE @num NUMERIC
DECLARE @money MONEY

SET @num = 99.99
SET @money = 99.99

SELECT SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@num + @money,'BaseType') as DataType
```

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet to test this!  Interestingly, replacing your MONEY type with DECIMAL yields NUMERIC.  It seem like NUMERIC has precedence over DECIMAL.  This may be a candidate for the most Microsoft thing ever.

Answer (score 2):

From the docs:

> Decimal and numeric are synonyms and can be used interchangeably.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

They are not merely closely related, they are the same thing from SQL Server's perspective and thus have the same conversion precedence.

Comment: I read that as well, I was just looking for expert confirmation that "functional equivalence" encompassed data precedence.  What would operations between Decimal and Numeric yield?

Comment: Have a look at Aaron Bertrand's answer here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75335/is-there-any-difference-at-all-between-numeric-and-decimal.  It's probably what you're looking for.  Aaron is certainly one of the experts out there!

Comment: I answered my own Numeric/Decimal question above thanks to userfl89's supplied code.  Numeric FTW.